# AFTER keyword in mysql ALTER table query

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I was browsing some code when I saw alter queries of the form:

```
alter table table_name add column tags varchar(25) default null after some_field;
```

Reading up on the [mysql docs for `ALTER` Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html), the purpose of the AFTER keyword is

> To add a column at a specific position within a table row, use FIRST or AFTER col_name. The default is to add the column last. You can also use FIRST and AFTER in CHANGE or MODIFY operations to reorder columns within a table.

When should one use this keyword, and would it be advisable to run it frequently to alter tables which have large number(millions) of rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use it when you want a new column you add to an existing table should not be at the end of the column list but at a specific position.

Example: Existing table `persons`

```
persons: id firstname, lastname, password, permissions
```

If you now want to add a new column `fullname` you might want to put it directly after `lastname` instead at the end of the column list. Then use `AFTER` to make it look like this

```
persons: id firstname, lastname, fullname, password, permissions
```

instead of that

```
persons: id firstname, lastname, password, permissions, fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

As the answer lies within your quote, To **re-order** the columns in a table, we mostly use `AFTER` or `FIRST` Keywords while creating a new column.